# Divs that resize or wrap

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to put a bunch of divs inside another one, and do something like the way table columns will resize to fit the space available, but in this case if the divs inside get shrunk to a minimum size they will wrap instead.

I have something like

```
<div style="width: 100%">
  <div style="float: left; min-width:30px; padding: 4px">Text 1</div>
  <div style="float: left; min-width:30px; padding: 4px">Text 2</div>
  <div style="float: left; min-width:30px; padding: 4px">Text 3</div>
  <div style="float: left; min-width:30px; padding: 4px">Text 4</div>
  <div style="float: left; min-width:30px; padding: 4px">Text 5</div>
</div>
```

and that does the wrapping correctly, but there doesn't seem to make the inner ones expand when there is room to fit them all on one line.  Can this be done now (keeping in mind I have to support browser that don't implement FlexBox yet)?

Comment: [This any good for you?](http://jsfiddle.net/ekGYV/)

Comment: @musefan, that's awesome!  Make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want, but you may want to set a percentage based width for the innner elements.

```
.cell {
   width:19%;
}
```

with your HTML like this:

```
<div style="width: 100%">
  <div class="cell" style="float: left; min-width:30px; padding: 4px">Text 1</div>
  ...
</div>
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ekGYV/)

Comment: Oh crap - I forgot that width doesn't include margin, border or padding, so if I saw "width 11%;" I can't actually get 9 elements in unless I remove the margin and padding.